# Importing CSV file with Quoted ( " ) quote ( ' ) - import is mismatching quote types

Tags: mysql, database, csv, import, import-from-csv

I am importing some data from a CSV file into a MySQL db. This has been workign well until I had a row come up which uses a single quote in the `Description` field.

The problematic row in the CSV is this:

```
"2019","3982","2018-12-16","black, height - 16.0 ', matte, waterproof, ellipsoid","42","PXC Mfg Inc","emarkham@______.com"
```

The SQL import is

```
LOAD DATA INFILE :file
            INTO TABLE $table_name
            FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
            LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
            IGNORE 1 LINES
            (Year,Price,StockDate,Description,Quantity,Supplier,Contact)
```

Given that all columns are double quoted, I would *expect* the result to be

```
 Year | Price | StockDate  | Description                                          | Quantity | Supplier    | Contact
------+-------+------------+------------------------------------------------------+----------+-------------+---------------------
 2019 |  3982 | 2018-12-16 | black, height - 16.0 ', matte, waterproof, ellipsoid | 42       | PXC Mfg Inc | emarkham@______.com
```

but what I *actually* got was

```
 Year | Price | StockDate  | Description          | Quantity  | Supplier  | Contact 
------+-------+------------+----------------------+-----------+-----------+----------
 2019 | 3982  | 2018-12-16 | black, height - 16.0 | 0         | waterproof| ellipsoid
```

As you can see the single quote (indicating 16 inches) has been interpreted as the end of that value. This is certainly not the desired result.

Anyone know how to correct this?

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem.

Comment: Thank you for trying. Can I ask what version of MySQL you tested on?

Comment: I'm on MySQL 5.5.60.